# What does the default sorting in Perl sort by on an array?

Tags: perl, sorting

I am reading some Perl code that sorts an array of hashes

```
uniq sort @{$ProjectData{$project}{Packages}}
```

I am not clear on whether this is sorting by the key of the hash, the key+value of the hash, or the memory address of the hash.  Also, I'm not clear on whether uniq is stable or not.  I am going to write my own compare function, but it seems or work as is, so I'd appreciate if someone could clear up what is happening currently.

Comment: [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) uses string comparison by default if you do not supply a block or sub to define the sorting method.

Answer (score 1):

If `$ProjectData{$project}{Packages}` is a reference to an array of hash references, then Perl will stringify all those references to something like `HASH(0xf1f6d290)` and sort them as strings

Effectively it's sorting by memory address, but that's really not very useful and you may as well drop the `sort`, leaving you with

```
uniq @{ $ProjectData{$project}{Packages} }
```

If you're using `List::Util::uniq` then it's stable, but unless you sort the data by something a bit more useful it really doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

`sort` sorts the scalars passed to in on the stack<sup>[1]</sup>. In your case, the scalars placed on the stack are the elements of the array referenced by `$ProjectData{$project}{Packages}`.

The default compare function sorts the values in ascending lexical order.

```
 sort LIST
```

is short for

```
 sort { $a cmp $b } LIST
```

This means the elements to compare are stringified, and compared character-by-character. This sorts `abc` before `def`, and `123` before `13`.

But you're comparing the stringification of references. The following are examples of stringification of references:

```
$ perl -E'say {}'
HASH(0x1a36ff8)

$ perl -E'say bless({}, "SomeClass");'
SomeClass=HASH(0x41d0a28)
```

As you can surmise, the only thing you can count on `sort` doing when given references is placing identical references together. It won't place references to identical hashes together, only references to the same hash.

---

`uniq` from List::MoreUtils is stable.

> The order of elements in the returned list is the same as in LIST.

It also uses a lexical comparison of the of the scalars. This means it will only remove references to the same hash, not references to identical hashes.

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper=Dumper -MList::MoreUtils=uniq -e'
   my $x = { a => 234, b => 345 };
   my $y = $x;
   my $z = { a => 234, b => 345 };
   print(Dumper([ uniq $x, $y, $z ]));
'
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'b' => 345,
            'a' => 234
          },
          {
            'b' => 345,
            'a' => 234
          }
        ];
```

---

Tip: Unless you're using a method of removing duplicates that requires sorted input, it makes more sense to remove the duplicates before sorting the values.

```
sort +uniq @{$ProjectData{$project}{Packages}}
```

(The `+` prevents `uniq` from being used as `sort`'s compare function.)

But since all that `sort` will meaningfully accomplish when given references is placing identical references together, and since `uniq` already eliminated identical references, the above can be simplified to

```
uniq @{$ProjectData{$project}{Packages}}
```

---

It's far more likely that you want to filter out references to duplicate hashes rather than references to the same hash. Here's how you can do that:

```
use JSON::XS qw( );

my $json_serializer = JSON::XS->new->canonical;

my %seen;
my @uniques = grep !$seen{ $json_serializer->encode($_) }++, @references;
```

For example,

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper=Dumper -MJSON::XS -e'
   my $json_serializer = JSON::XS->new->canonical;
   my $x = { a => 234, b => 345 };
   my $y = $x;
   my $z = { a => 234, b => 345 };
   my %seen;
   print(Dumper([ grep !$seen{ $json_serializer->encode($_) }++, $x, $y, $z ]));
'
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'b' => 345,
            'a' => 234
          }
        ];
```

---

1. Ok, technically, it can actually be passed an array as an optimization, but that's internal details.

Comment: Added explanation of how to remove duplicate hashes.

Answer (score 0):

As for `sort @{$ProjectData{$project}{Packages}}`, that's just sorting the contents of the array `@{$ProjectData{$project}{Packages}}` using the default sorting.

According to the docs it uses "standard string comparison order" which means it uses `cmp`. It means it sorts by turning the arguments into strings and comparing them one character at a time in ***the order they appear in their character encoding***. We used to call this "ASCIIbetical" but now with UTF-8 it's not necessarily ASCII.

Some examples.

```
# 1, 20, 3 because it considers them "1", "20", "3".
sort 1, 3, 20;

# a, z
sort "z", "a";

# Z, a because ASCII Z is 90 and ASCII a is 97.
sort "Z", "a";

# z, ä because UTF-8 z is 122 and UTF-8 ä is 195 164
use utf8;
sort "z", "ä";
```